# Where does NetBeans store it's SSH connections

Tags: netbeans, ssh

This has been driving me nuts for a while now. I have a lot of SSH connections in NetBeans that are old, but I can not seem to find a place to remove them.

Not here that I am not talking about the PHP remote connection, but SSH terminal connections. See screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it here?

C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\dlight\nativeexecution.properties

Answer (score 2):

It's stored in a file:  C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\cnd\remote.properties

Comment: Still can't seem to find it, but I will re-install Netbeans and see if it pops up this time. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, even after a clean install and new configuration I am unable to fund this folder. So I am putting this question back up.

Comment: Can you do a file search in your home directory looking for 'remote.properties', preferably in your AppData directory?

Comment: I did exactly that, but I did not get any results back. I am running the newest version of Netbeans PHP on Windows, maybe that makes a difference?

Answer (score 2):

In netbeans 8 all the connections are stored under this folder:

C:\Users\ *yourusername* \AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\keyring\win32.properties

Look for the lines that start with "remote.user.info"

Answer (score 0):

For me they are in

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2rc\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\php\project\RemoteConnections